# Need to extract claim based token from list of users

Tags: sharepoint, csom

I have a peculiar requirement, I have list of users and need to get an output like below using CSOM. Thanks a million in advance.

**Input:**
adam@contoso.com
eve@contoso.com

**Output:**
i:0#.f|membership|adam@contoso.com
i:0#.f|membership|eve@contoso.com

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean, string concatenation does not help? Or? Check out this article: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13921.sharepoint-20102013-claims-encoding.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There is a really useful function on the web object `EnsureUser` that accepts an email as a parameter. This function will return a `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.User` that has a property `LoginName` which contains the desired claim information that you are after:

```
var user = cc.Web.EnsureUser("adam@contoso.com");
cc.Load(user, u => u.LoginName);
cc.ExecuteQuery();
var claimToken = user.LoginName;
```

Hopefully this will help you get the results you need.